# Why does req.sessions return an empty object instead of the passed value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies

I'm learning express.js and I'm stuck on one little problem.
How can I save sessions in the browser so I don't have to log in every time. I use cookie-session. I send the login data downloaded from the form for validation using the POST method to endpoint ./login. After successfully passing the validation, it saves sessions in this way: req.session.admin = 1;, and then using redirect, it redirects to the admin endpoint. After redirecting to ./admin, I try to read if there is a previously saved req.session.admin session. The above action returns me undefined, and the req.session itself returns an empty object {}. I tried console.log on the ./login endpoint and yes, everything is OK i.e. it returns 1 and on the ./admin endpoint it is undfined.
My question to you is: Has anything changed recently in the implementation of cookie-session (although I don't think so, because I do it according to the documentation available on npm), or do I need to install some package besides cookie-session?

Save the session

```
.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  if (password === body.password && login === body.login) {
    req.session.admin = 1;
    res.redirect('/admin');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

This is where my problem arises, because the session is not saved and each time the validation fails, I return to login

```
.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.admin) {
    res.redirect('/login');
    return;
  }
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `req.session.admin = 1` does not save session, but it assigns value to separate request. Each request is independent.

You have to return some information to client (e.g token) for further using. Token should be sent in each request in appropriate header and express should verify it.

What's more you should not send credentials in plain text.

What I recommend is to familiarise yourself with JWT concept https://jwt.io/introduction

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I'm just learning this tool and I want to make it work first, and then I will improve it and apply best practices.

Comment: Totally agree, but in this way you won't make it run. Request is created on client side. You need pass from server side information about successful login and return to the client.

Comment: And how do I do it?  Do you have any guide or tutorial.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

Comment: I did exactly what it says and it doesn't work for me.  I already think it's Webstorm's fault

Comment: Do you properly read and add cookie on the client side?